# Stuck on Google Verification after performing a hard reset

Tags: factory-reset, google

I have Oplus phone with 5.1 Lillipop that stuck in google verification. Its says that I need to enter my previous gmail account to continue, but i don't have any access of it. I already forgot how I create that account. I have searched on google about this but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[**Oplus phone**](http://m.gadgets.ndtv.com/oplus-xonphone-5-1798) is powered by Mediatek chipset (MT6582). Just flashing the FRP partition will bypass the lock. Require paid softwares.

Method 2: 
Try one of many ways to get a temporary access to the device. When you're in, do the following:
*(I won't show you how to access the device. You'll have to find how to by yourself)*

- Download this [APK file](http://www58.zippyshare.com/d/hnbreNJF/31003/com.frpbypass-1.0.apk) and install it.
- When installed, open it. You'll be asked to enter your Google credentials (E-mail and password).
- Afterwards, factory reset the device (from the menu or from the recovery)
- Now when the phone boots, it will ask for Google account, enter that E-mail and password (the one you previously entered before the reset).
- Et voilà. FRP bypassed.

Disclaimer: 
***Use this method only if you forgot the account associated with the device. Do not use it if it is a stolen device.***